# How does direct access array sort work when it sorts keys instead of values?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

When watching [MIT OpenCourseWare 5. Linear Sorting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yndgIDO0zQQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63EdVPNLG3ToM6LaEUuStEY&index=9), the professor talked about Direct Access Array sorting:

```py
def direct_access_sort(A):
    "Sort A assuming items have distinct non-negative keys"
    u = 1 + max([x.key for x in A]) # O(n) find maximum key
    D = [None] * u # O(u) direct access array
    for x in A: # O(n) insert items
        D[x.key] = x
    i = 0
    for key in range(u): # O(u) read out items in order
        D[key] is not None:
            A[i] = D[key]
            i += 1
```

Suppose all keys are unique non-negative integers in range {0, . . . , u − 1}, so n ≤ u,
the algorithm described here is basically:

1. Insert each item into a direct access array with size u in Θ(n)
2. Return items in order they appear in direct access array in Θ(u)

I am wondering how this can be described as "sorting", because it seems to me that the only thing sorted here is the *key* instead of the *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `D` will store the full object (key and value) from the items in `A`,
so when inserting back into `A`, it is the full object: `A[i] = D[key]`

Example:
Lets pretend we're sorting an array of people by height, each having a key equal to their height.
The input would look like this (excluding additional properties for simplicity):

```
A = [{key: 160}, {key: 150}, {key: 200}, {key: 188}]
```

This line finds the max height in A:

```
u = 1 + max([x.key for x in A]) # O(n) find maximum key
```

In our case, that is 200.

This line creates a new array of size `u`, so an array of size 200 even though we only have 4 elements in `A`:

```
D = [None] * u # O(u) direct access array
```

This loop inserts the whole object (including key) into the new array, at the index of the key.

```
for x in A: # O(n) insert items
    D[x.key] = x
```

So it is an array of size 200, but only 4 indices have a value (those indices are the heights 150, 160, 188, 200).
The rest are `None`.

When inserting elements into the array, we need a counter - that is what `i` is for, so it starts at 0.

```
i = 0
```

Now we iterate from 0 to the max key (200).

```
for key in range(u):
```

Since we only have 4 positions with values, we need to check if the current height we're testing, is one of those 4:

```
D[key] is not None: # (I think this line needs an `if` in front of it)
```

If the key is in the array, we overwrite the current index (i) in `A` with the object with that height.

```
A[i] = D[key]
```

This will first be when i = 0, and key = 150 (since 150 will be the first match, when going from 0-200)

Finally, `i` is incremented so we don't insert at the same position multiple times.

```
i += 1
```

So the values while inserting will be this:

```
i = 0, key = 150, D[key] = {key: 150}
i = 1, key = 160, D[key] = {key: 160}
i = 2, key = 188, D[key] = {key: 188}
i = 3, key = 200, D[key] = {key: 200}
```

Consider firing up a debugger, and see what the objects look like while this runs.
It achieves a lot of linearity, but requires the input to be *distinct non-negative*.
Additionally, imagine sorting 10 elements with keys in the millions/billions - the arrays and iterations would become very large.